# VBA return dynamic array and assign to variable

Tags: excel, vba

[Return dynamic array from function VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614791/return-dynamic-array-from-function-vba) got me part of the way on this problem. I realized I should know size prior to invoking the function.

```
Function GetHeadersFromRange(DataRange As Range, Size As Integer) As Variant
    Dim Column As Integer
    Dim Headers As Variant
    ReDim Headers(0 To Size)

    For Column = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count
        Headers(Column) = DataRange(1, Column).Value
    Next
    GetHeadersFromRange = Headers
End Function 

Sub TestGetHeadersFromRange()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set TestSheet = wb.Sheets.Add()

    TestSheet.Range("A1").Value = "my_header"
    TestSheet.Range("A2").Value = "val"

    Dim DataRange As Range: Set DataRange = TestSheet.Range("A1:A2")
    Dim Size As Integer: Size = DataRange.Columns.Count
    Dim Result As Variant

    ' Gets type mismatch
    Set Result = GetHeadersFromRange(DataRange, Size)
End Sub
```

Not entirely sure what to do here. I need to use this function in multiple places which is why it is a function in the first place.

Edit: Clarify problem
`Set Result = GetHeadersFromRange(...)` gets a type mismatch.

Comment: Because your UDF returns a 1-D array of values *(not ranges)* , you should not use `Set`

Comment: You've just declared Result as Variant and then you use Set Result!? Could you explain what will you do with Result in the Future?

Comment: *Headers* is zero based but you don't adjust *Size*. If there are five columns then Headers is 0 to 5 for a total of six array elements. You ignore `Headers(0)`.

Comment: Always helps to explain exactly what the problem is.  Is it just the "Type mismatch" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Header Function

### Improvement

- Your error occurs because you are using `Set` (**used for objects**)
  on an array.
- A more efficient (faster) way than looping through a range is **looping
  through an array**.
- When you copy a range to a variant (possibly array), if the range
  contains **one cell**, the variant will contain **one value only**. But if
  the range contains **multiple cells**, it will be an **array**, whose size is
  returned with `UBound`. Therefore there is no need for a `Size` argument.
- `IsArray` is used to determine if a variant is an array. In our case we can check if the number of columns (elements) is greater than 1 instead.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetHeadersFromRange(DataRange As Range) As Variant

    Dim vntR As Variant   ' Range Variant
    Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
    Dim Noe As Long       ' Number of Elements
    Dim j As Long         ' Range Array Column Counter,
                          ' Header Array Element Counter

    With DataRange
        ' Calculate Number of Elements.
        Noe = .Columns.Count
        ' Calculate Header Range.
        ' Copy Header Range to Range Variant.
        vntR = .Resize(1, Noe)
        ' Note: Range Variant (vntR) is a 2D 1-based 1-row array only if
        '       DataRange contains more than one column. Otherwise it is
        '       a variant containing one value.
    End With

    '' Check if Range Variant is an array.
    'If IsArray(vntR) Then
    ' Check if Number of Elements is greater than 1.
    If Noe > 1 Then
        ' Resize 1D 0-based Header Array to number of columns (2) in Range
        ' Array minus 1 (0-based).
        ReDim vntH(Noe - 1)
        ' Loop through columns of Range Array.
        For j = 1 To Noe
            ' Write value at first row (1) and current column (j) of Range
            ' Array to current element (j-1) of Header Array.
            vntH(j - 1) = vntR(1, j)
        Next
      Else
        ' Resize 1D 0-based Header Array to one element only (0).
        ReDim vntH(0)
        ' Write Range Variant value to only element of Header Array.
        vntH(0) = vntR
    End If

    GetHeadersFromRange = vntH

End Function


Sub TestGetHeadersFromRange()

    Dim TestSheet As Worksheet  ' Source Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range      ' Data Range
    Dim Result As Variant       ' Result Variant (possibly Array)
    Dim i As Long               ' Result Array Element Counter

    ' Add a new worksheet (Source Worksheet).
    ' Create a reference to the newly added Source Worksheet.
    Set TestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With TestSheet
        ' Add some values.
        .Range("A1").Value = "my_header"
        .Range("A2").Value = "val"
        .Range("B1").Value = "my_header2"
        .Range("B2").Value = "val2"
    End With

' Test 1:
    Debug.Print "Test1:"
    ' Create a reference to DataRange.
    Set DataRange = TestSheet.Range("A1:A2")
    ' Write Data Range to 1D 0-based Result Array.
    Result = GetHeadersFromRange(DataRange)
    ' Loop through elements of Result Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(Result)
        ' Write current element of Result Array to Immediate window.
        Debug.Print Result(i)
    Next

' Test 2:
    Debug.Print "Test2:"
    ' Create a reference to DataRange.
    Set DataRange = TestSheet.Range("A1:B2")
    ' Write Data Range to 1D 0-based Result Variant.
    Result = GetHeadersFromRange(DataRange)
    ' Loop through elements of Result Array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(Result)
        ' Write current element of Result Array to Immediate window.
        Debug.Print Result(i)
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot.

Comment: If you are trying to get a zero-based 1-D array from one row and many columns you need to double up application.transpose. If you want a one-based 2-D array you don't need to transpose anything.

Comment: Can you explain the difference? I am using this in conjunction w/ VBA-Web and need to send a JSON request that takes an array as an argument.

Comment: @ user11198948: When you have tried the code, you will notice that the Result Range contains a column with the headers, not a row, which I understood OP wants.

Comment: I definitely don't need a 2D array.

Comment: @Adam: I've edited my Answer. You will most certainly need a 1D 0-based array. This should be an efficient way to achieve your task.

Comment: If you are happy with a 1-dim **1-based** array you can shorten the function code to a *one-liner*: `GetHeadersFromRange = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(DataRange.Value, 1, 0)))`

Comment: This appeared to get the array as desired.